Multigraph in PyVis network
I'm trying to render a multigraph in PyVis with
from pyvis.network import Network

net = Network()
net.show_buttons()
net.add_node(1)
net.add_node(2)
net.add_edge(1,2, label="TEST", physics=False, smooth={'type': 'dynamic', 'roundness': 0.4})
net.add_edge(1, 2, label="TAST", physics=False, smooth={'type': 'dynamic', 'roundness': 0.6})
display(HTML(net.show("test.html", notebook=False)))

However it only displays the first edge that I added.
I  only put the smoothing in the edge functions because I saw a recommendation elsewhere to do this, in order to render a multigraph -- but it doesn't work.
